# Do I need an IDE to develop Android Cordova Apps?

Tags: android, cordova

Is it required to have Intellij or Eclipse or can one simply write apps by simply using some editor like Sublime and Cordova CLI? Is there something I cannot do without using an IDE?

Answer (score 0):

since a cordova application project conists of html and js files a text editor would be enough , i am using visual community code [1](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)

Answer (score 0):

No, its pretty easy to develop cordova not using an IDE. In fact it gives you a good understanding of whats really going on.

Take a look at the docs http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface and create the example to get an idea. After that its just using the command line tool to add plugins and your editor to write html/js

Answer (score 0):

You might miss the simulator that comes with the IDE. In particular, XCode. Testing on IOS simulator and publishing to the App Store is relatively easier using XCode.

But is IDE required? Not really.

Answer (score 0):

If you need custom plugin for your app, you have to use an IDE since java classes from different packages must be imported. Thus, this work can be very waste of time without an IDE like Android Studio.